# Listview displays images only after scroll

Tags: android, listview, scroll, lazy-loading

I'm new to android programming, and i'm writing a piece of code based on Fedor's LazyList example. The idea is to load images and text from a feed, so that works fine but a little prob occured :
Images are downloaded and cached on SD Card, queued and displayed the problem is that the listview displayes the default images (on drawable folder) until i scroll it up or down there it shows the real images.

Please help.

Here's a link to code [link text](http://db.tt/xeEgyTd)

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please look at my sample code carefully. You should add `imageView.setTag()` before `imageLoader.DisplayImage()` in `MessageListAdapter`.

Comment: Thanks Fedor, finally it works, I just added this holder.image.setTag(Message.getiLink().toString());

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you scroll getview function in the adapter is called and images are loaded in that function. You need to use some good / faster code to load images.
I would suggest you to try below link.

http://umakantpatil.com/posts/android-listview-with-separate-headers-and-images-loading-from-remote-server

It has headers in the list, you can just use the code of loading images from that example.

Answer (score -2):

change

```
getActivity().getApplicationContext() = getActivity().getBaseContext()
```